# Logic for Moving the columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as below:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="row0">0</tr>
    <tr id="row1">1</tr>
    <tr id="row2">2</tr>
    <tr id="row3">3</tr>
    <tr id="row4">4</tr>
    <tr id="row5">5</tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to move my rows up and down and I created a function as below

```
function moveColumn(i){

let next = parseInt(i) + 1;

$('#row' + parseInt(i)).insertAfter($('#row' + next));
```

}

but the logic doesn't work because if you work with ids and move a column down, then can't click again because now 0 is under 1.(for example)

what would be good logic to move my columns?
is there a way to tell one row to inserAfter the next row using jquery?

**UPDATE**

Looking for something like

```
    $('#row' + parseInt(i)).insertAfter($('tr:eq(next)'));
```

Comment: Don't use IDs at all. It's worthless. You don't need an ID to know which ROW is selected etc.

Comment: Also, if you want to move rows, than why is your function called `moveColumn`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah as I explained I'm aware of that. I'm looking for another solution thats why I posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **index** and jQuery's `.eq()` to target elements, and `.insertBefore()` to move elements.

```js
const moveChild = (from, to, $par) => {
  const $ch = $par.children();
  $ch.eq(from).insertBefore($ch.eq(to));
};

const $par = $("table tbody");
moveChild(4, 0, $par); // move index 4 to index 0
moveChild(3, 1, $par); // and then move index 3 to index 1
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```